# unofficial Google Reader API on Android not working

Tags: android

Well, previously I can get the data from this url "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="los+angeles,ca"&daddr=hollywood,ca&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml" but recently I am not getting any data instead a map is shown. Please anyone if there is any alternate way to get the same data or any other source. or am I doing anything wrong

Comment: From the title, you are obviously doing something wrong - never use unofficial, unpublished apis. They are bound to change without notice and there is no one to blame; your application may break.